# Disable Predictive Keyboard Strip (iOS 8) for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

This post explains how to prevent the new predictive text bar appearing during UITextField input:

[Disable UITextField Predictive Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767522/disable-uitextfield-predictive-text)

But I have been unable to adapt that to a UITableViewCell. How do I access the textfield of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it on a UITableViewCell because the cell does not use a keyboard. you need to set it to the text fields subviews of the cell.

**Edit post-comment**

There are many ways to access a field in a UITableViewCell. I'm including the two most common.

1. Tag the field in storyboard then you can write in `viewForRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   UITextField *tf=(UITextField *)[yourCell viewWithTag:yourTag];
   ```
2. Sub class your UITableViewCell (I think this results in the cleanest code). Now you can create an IBOutlet for each sub view in directly in the class of your cell.

Comment: This is what I'm looking to do, but don't know how to access that field. Have clarified the original post. Thanks.

Comment: You should make the question's post more descriptive to help the most people possible. Maybe something like: "accessing a sub view of UITableViewCell"