# SwiftUI: Is it possible to turn off predictive text for a TextField

Tags: textfield, swiftui

I would like to turn off predictive text/autocorrect for a `TextField` in SwiftUI. Looks like this was possible in with `UITextField`:
[Disable UITextField Predictive Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767522/disable-uitextfield-predictive-text)

I checked the Apple documentation for `TextField` and googled, but can't find anything about this.

Has anyone found a way to disable the predictive text/autocomplete for a TextField?

Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Seems like it is now possible using Xcode 11 Beta 5. There is a new modifier to disable the autocorrection on TextField

```
func disableAutocorrection(_ disable: Bool?) -> some View
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/3367734-disableautocorrection?changes=latest_beta

Edit:
Modifier *disableAutocorrection* is deprecated in **iOS 16.1**. The new modifier is *autocorrectionDisabled*:

```
func autocorrectionDisabled(_ disable: Bool = true) -> some View
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentedwindowcontent/autocorrectiondisabled(_:)?changes=latest_beta&language=_5

Comment: it's not deprecated in iOS16

Comment: this doesn't work, the suggestion bar still showing

Comment: This only works for me when I also set `.keyboardType(.asciiCapable)` or `.keyboardType(.alphabet)` [as suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279641/2030).

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
.disableAutocorrection(true)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the suggestion bar still showing

Answer (score 8):

For the iOS 16.2 SDK, I needed to do this:

```swift
.keyboardType(.alphabet)
.textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
.autocorrectionDisabled(true)
```

(`oneTimePasscode` is an old UIKit hack to achieve the same result. It feels dirty to me, and I wouldn't be surprised if this behaviour changes again in the future...)

Comment: thanks for the answer! for me it was enough to apply keyboardType and autocorrectionDisabled

Comment: this helped me. `.keyboardType(.alphabet)` and `.autocorrectionDisabled(true)` are good enough

Answer (score 6):

Turns out you need to set the keyboard type to `.alphabet` for `.disableAutocorrection(true)` to work.

here is the extension I use:

```
extension View {
    func removePredictiveSuggestions() -> some View {
        self.keyboardType(.alphabet)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: `.keyboardType(.asciiCapable)` also works!)  xCode 14.2, iOS 16

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode 12.3 Swift 5.3**

If you need to disable autocorrection on multiple `TextField`s, or indeed add other modifiers, then create a custom TextField:

```
struct TextFieldCustom: View {
    
    let title: String
    let text: Binding<String>
    
    init(_ title: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: text)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            // add any other modifiers that you want
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
Form {
    Section(header: Text("Details")) {
        TextFieldCustom("Field1", text: $field1)
        TextFieldCustom("Feild2", text: $field2)
        TextFieldCustom("Field3", text: $field3)
    }
}
```