Keyboard glitch while typing
I am curious how to solve this issue when typing into a textfield. When i begin typing into a textfield, the keyboard top half glitches, then also dips down. Here is a Example gif  of the issue at hand.
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
...
...
...

                CustomTextField(icon: "mail", placeholder: "Email", text: $email)
                CustomTextField(icon: "lock", placeholder: "Password", text: $password, isSecure: true)

            }
        }
    }
}

CustomTextField
struct CustomTextField: View {
    var icon: String
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var isSecure: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: icon)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            if isSecure {
                SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
            } else {
                TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

I am unsure why this is occuring. I have attached a video for demonstration.

Have you attached your video to question?

Try removing the viewModel because that's what View structs are for.

@malhal I am unable to do so because I use the viewmodel to make a function call to log user when the sign in button is clicked that i did not add here. What was the intuition for removing the viewmodel?

@duckSern1108 I just added it! sorry about that. Here it is too!  https://i.sstatic.net/FfGACpVo.gif

@jake42 have you try this approach from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213479/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-predictive-text-for-a-textfield

have you tried adding .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom) to your VStack?

@jake42 you don't need objects just for a func, try to limit use of objects
